# Как сделать ссылку на печать внутренней страницы или файла сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, print, jpeg

Мне нужно сделать  печать jpg  по внутренней ссылке.
Пока что я нашел, что он скрипт для печать текущей страницы.

```
<a href="javascript:(print());" class="button">
```

Однако мне нужна ссылка для печати одной и той же страницы на в всех.
Подскажите, как видоизменить скрипт для подстановки URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print() это метод браузера, это значит, что ты не можешь печатать то, что не отображено на экране. Ты можешь, однако, попробовать выводить страницу в скрытый iframe и установить для него "видимый" CSS вроде display:block; для @media print. Ну или использовать headless-браузер на стороне сервера, или использовать один из десятков веб-сервисов, которые на URL отдают его вид в PNG.

```
@media print
    {
        .printiframe, .printiframe *
        {
            display: block !important;
        }
        body .maincontent {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```